# Распределние объектов внутри 3-х мерного объекта

Tags: алгоритм, 3d

Например есть некая сфера с координатами (X, Y, Z) и радиусом D, и есть N сфер радиусом d0, d1, ..., dN, которые надо распределить внутри первой используя, например, нормальный закон распределения. При этом объекты должны выдерживать минимальное расстояние между друг-другом, и, само-сабой, эти объекты не могут пересекаться. Может кто решал подобную задачу или есть идеи на счет алгоритма? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Такие алгоритмы называются по-английски "packing" (упаковка). Напр. [sphere packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing)

Если подключить физику, можно предположить, что сферы подвижны, и отталкиваются друг от друга, и от стенок. Видел много реализаций такого для плоской окружности и кругов внутри – "circle packing".

Answer (score 1):

Вы ничего не сказали про диаметры остальных "маленьких" сфер (дальше буду считать, что они одинаковы для ясности). Не знаю, где у Вас матожидание распределения центров сфер, надеюсь, оно находится на расстоянии большем, чем радиус мелких сфер.

И так, нам нужно нагенерить N сфер и уместить их в большую сферу. 
Предлагаю первую точку(центр первой сферы) поместить в матожидание распределения. 
Дальше, согласно распределению, генерируем следующий центр. Делаем проверку на то, что не вылезли за пределы большой сферы(если вылезли, то генерим следующий центр). Если так получилось, что расстояние между центрами получилось меньше 2 радиусов, то последний центр просто "сдвигаем" вдоль прямой, соединяющей центры до нужного расстояния. 
Продолжая вот такие итерации, можно набрать необходимое число мелких сфер внутри большой. 
К сожалению, вы мало что сказали про параметры задачи, не могу предложить что-то более дельное...

Comment: Диаметры малых сфер заданы отдельно, т.е. они не обязательно равны. Мат. ожидаение я думаю все-таки центр.
> Дальше, согласно распределению, генерируем следующий центр.

Вот это-то и интересует больше всего. Не могу сообразить как это сделать. Получить каждую координату по отдельности?

Comment: ну раз так, то, думаю, можно попытаться моим алгоритмом попробовать... правда он не слишком изящен - просто написал, что первое в голову пришло

Comment: Честно говоря, немного переживаю за то, что можно ли так расположить все сферы внутри большой - все-таки могут быть такие конфигурации фигур, при которых не все N штук влезут...

Comment: > Честно говоря, немного переживаю за то, что можно ли так расположить все сферы внутри большой - все-таки могут быть такие конфигурации фигур, при которых не все N штук влезут...

Ну для простоты будем считать, что они гарантировано туда все поместятся

Comment: Ну раз так, то мой топорный способ подойдет)

Comment: А что все-таки на счет
>> Дальше, согласно распределению, генерируем следующий центр.

Вот это-то и интересует больше всего. Не могу сообразить как это сделать. Получить каждую координату по отдельности?

Comment: Отличный вопрос)    
Да, думаю получение каждой координаты нормальным законом сработает - единственный минус - это, как мне кажется, частенько придется перегенерировать результаты за счет того, что новый центр слишком близко к остальным...

Comment: Вот и я так же думаю:)